# How to fix: AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm currently working based on this video : https://youtu.be/7A0HCGySkfA?si=TSRPHMgv8TAhch7Q
Trying to import API into Touchdesigner.
But when I followed the process up to 7:30 in that video, this problem occurred.
I think this error is caused because I'm using macOS.
But I don't know how to fix it, where to fix it, or what to search for.
I'm a novice designer trying coding for the first time, so please bear with me even if this question is very basic...

**Whole code**

```
import json
import codecs
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import sys

BaseURL = 'https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/'

ApiKey='Here was my API Key'
#UnitGroup sets the units of the output - us or metric
UnitGroup='us'

#Location for the weather data
Location='Washington,DC'

#Optional start and end dates
#If nothing is specified, the forecast is retrieved. 
#If start date only is specified, a single historical or forecast day will be retrieved
#If both start and and end date are specified, a date range will be retrieved
StartDate = ''
EndDate=''

#JSON or CSV 
#JSON format supports daily, hourly, current conditions, weather alerts and events in a single JSON package
#CSV format requires an 'include' parameter below to indicate which table section is required
ContentType="json"

#include sections
#values include days,hours,current,alerts
Include="current"

#basic query including location
ApiQuery=BaseURL + Location

#append the start and end date if present
if (len(StartDate)):
    ApiQuery+="/"+StartDate
    if (len(EndDate)):
        ApiQuery+="/"+EndDate

#Url is completed. Now add query parameters (could be passed as GET or POST)
ApiQuery+="?"

#append each parameter as necessary
if (len(UnitGroup)):
    ApiQuery+="&unitGroup="+UnitGroup

if (len(ContentType)):
    ApiQuery+="&contentType="+ContentType

if (len(Include)):
    ApiQuery+="&include="+Include

ApiQuery+="&key="+ApiKey

print(' - Running query URL: ', ApiQuery)
print()

try: 
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(ApiQuery)
except urllib.error.HTTPError  as e:
    ErrorInfo= e.read().decode() 
    print('Error code: ', e.code, ErrorInfo)
    sys.exit()
except  urllib.error.URLError as e:
    ErrorInfo= e.read().decode() 
    print('Error code: ', e.code,ErrorInfo)
    sys.exit()
    
weatherData = json.loads(data.read().decode('utf-8'))

op('request_output').text = json.dumps(weatherData)

debug(ApiQuery)
```

**Error when it runs**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<Textport>", line 1
td.tdError: File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1422, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/project1/API", line 60
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/project1/API", line 66
AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'read'
Results of run operation resulted in exception.
python >>>
```

I just hope this code works as normal as in the video.

Comment: why do you use `e.read()`? Variable `e` is probably as string and it doesn't have function `read()`. It may need `e.decode()` instead of `e.read().decode()`

Comment: it seems there is mistake in tutorial - author copied code from `except urllib.error.HTTPError  as e:` to `except urllib.error.URLError  as e:`  but `URLError` doesn't have `read()` nor `decode()`, nor `e.code`. It may need only `str(e)` or `e.reason` like `except urllib.error.URLError  as e: print(str(e))`

Comment: different problem is `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] `. It may need to update `OpenSSL` which is not part of Python but `C/C++` program and it may need to install (or update) with `brew`